How do Christians reconcile that Jacob conspired with his mother and stole the birthright from Esau?
Genesis 27

15And Rebekah took the finest clothes in the house that belonged to
her older son Esau, and she put them on her younger son Jacob. 16She
also put the skins of the young goats on his hands and on the smooth
part of his neck. 17Then she handed her son Jacob the tasty food and
bread she had made.
18So Jacob went to his father and said, “My father.”
“Here I am!” he answered. “Which one are you, my son?”
19Jacob said to his father, “I am Esau, your firstborn. I have done as
you told me. Please sit up and eat some of my game, so that you may
bless me.”
20But Isaac asked his son, “How did you ever find it so quickly, my
son?”
“Because the LORD your God brought it to me,” he replied.

In the description above, Jacob and his mother clearly conspire to steal Esau's birthright blessing. We also remember that Jacob took advantage of Esau's hunger by selling him a pot of stew for his birthright prior to this.
Jacob even lies when asked how he managed to get the game so soon telling his father that God provided it.

How does one reconcile that Jacob obtained the birthright with conspiracy, lies and deceit?

In considering your answer note Isaiah 61...particularly
Verses 10&11

The Year of the LORD’s Favor (Luke 4:16–30)
1The Spirit of the Lord GOD is on Me,
because the LORD has anointed Me
to preach good news to the poor.
He has sent Me to bind up the brokenhearted,
to proclaim liberty to the captives
and freedom to the prisoners,a
2to proclaim the year of the LORD’s favorb
and the day of our God’s vengeance,
to comfort all who mourn,
3to console the mourners in Zion—
to give them a crown of beauty for ashes,
the oil of joy for mourning,
and a garment of praise for a spirit of despair.
So they will be called oaks of righteousness,
the planting of the LORD, that He may be glorified.
4They will rebuild the ancient ruins;
they will restore the places long devastated;
they will renew the ruined cities,
the desolations of many generations.
5Strangers will stand and feed your flocks,
and foreigners will be your plowmen and vinedressers.
6But you will be called the priests of the LORD;
they will speak of you as ministers of our God;
you will feed on the wealth of nations,
and you will boast in their riches.
7Instead of shame, My people will have a double portion,
and instead of humiliation, they will rejoice in their share;
and so they will inherit a double portion in their land,
and everlasting joy will be theirs.
8For I, the LORD, love justice;
I hate robbery and iniquity;
in My faithfulness I will give them their recompense
and make an everlasting covenant with them.
9Their descendants will be known among the nations,
and their offspring among the peoples.
All who see them will acknowledge
that they are a people the LORD has blessed.

10I will rejoice greatly in the LORD,
my soul will exult in my God;
for He has clothed me with garments of salvation
and wrapped me in a robe of righteousness


And the description Paul gives us in Hebrews chapter 4:16

16Let us therefore come boldly to the throne of grace, that we may
obtain mercy and find grace to help in time of need.

There seems to be a similarity there, Jacob covered his true identity with skins and the saved do the same in the judgement. However Jacob doeent appear to me to have walked in boldly before his father...he was terrified he might be found out!
Also, after the blessing was given and the deception revealed, Jacob spent many years in excile fearing for his life...he was worried his brother would find him and kill him.
It seems to me that the blessing did not serve any purpose for Jacob until he recieved the forgiveness of his brother many years later (God changed his name to Israel around that time).
Given the above, how do we reconcile that Jacob clearly engaged in sinful behaviour in order to recieve the promise of salvation and thatin the example given in Hebrews, a little trickery is still manifest in that we take on those same sheep skins seemingly to hide our true nature and obtain grace?

There’s no problem for Christianity in acknowledging that men like Jacob were sinful and flawed in the OT. Even Moses, the greatest of the OT prophets, was denied entry to the promised land for his sin against God. At any rate, Esau sold his birthright to Jacob. So while his means were questionable, it was in fact Esau’s fault that he did not get blessed.

Which part of the long quote from Luke are you drawing attention to? Please [edit] it to be more concise. I agree with Ryan that there doesn't appear to be anything to reconcile here - no one is saying that Jacob's duplicity was righteous.

You have forgotten that God promised to Rebekah that the elder would serve the younger. And what is wrong with offering soup in exchange for a birthright ? It was Esau who sealed the deal by accepting it. When an older generation (Isaac) is no longer clear-sighted (spiritually) then the next generation has to get around that, yet without rebelling. There are great lessons to be learned in all this, but not if false accusations are being made.

@ Nijel J...False accusations? Do you not agree that Rebecca and Jacob tricked Isaac into giving Jacob the blessing through deception? Honestly, you don't recognise the issue there and need to carefully read the story again. The point is, Jacob obtained the birthright via sinful means...deceipt! Reconcile that!

@adam Nope. I don't see that at all. But then I am looking at the spiritual reasons for the methods used. No 'deception' at  all. The one who had the birthright who called himself 'Esau' . . . .  was Jacob. I can call myself any name I like. It is not a crime. And when it accurately indicates my rights, then it is valid. You don;t see things the way I see them, it seems.

Nijel, I do not even follow the relevance of your comment. You clearly are convinced that deception is a viable means of attaining salvation...through the works of men. This is exactly what Jacob did...its shown in the New Testament to be unbiblical.

AFter 24 hours...i have managed to resolve the dilemma posed by the above question
It is my genuine hope that this library retains this topic because it has significant theological importance to the doctrine of righteousness by faith versus works!
The facts of the story are that Jacob did obtain the birthright and its blessing through decept and did finally steal the blessing from his brother by tricking his own father into thinking he was Easau.
Jacob even made the false claim that it was God who provided the wild game so quickly in answer to Isaacs inquiry about the unusually fast return of his son with food.
Please note...
the answer could be far more extensive than what i have posted below. It could also include detail on the exact nature of the promise given to Abraham that was passed on down through the generations and the link back to the promise of salvation made to Eve in the garden of Eden (because ultimately, that is what the gospel is really all about
The answer
Rebekah and Jacob both knew that the birthright was foretold would go to the younger son:

Genesis 25
19This is the account of Abraham’s son Isaac. Abraham became the
father of Isaac, 20and Isaac was forty years old when he married
Rebekah, the daughter of Bethuel the Aramean from Paddan-aramb and the
sister of Laban the Aramean.
21Later, Isaac prayed to the LORD on behalf of his wife, because she
was barren. And the LORD heard his prayer, and his wife Rebekah
conceived.
22But the children inside her struggled with each other, and she said,
“Why is this happening to me?” So Rebekah went to inquire of the LORD,
23and He declared to her:
“Two nations are in your womb,
and two peoples from within you will be separated;
one people will be stronger than the other,
and the older will serve the younger.”c
24When her time came to give birth, there were indeed twins in her
womb. 25The first one came out red, covered with hair like a fur coat;
so they named him Esau.d 26After this, his brother came out grasping
Esau’s heel; so he was named Jacob.e And Isaac was sixty years old
when the twins were born.

What we find is that neither Rebekah nor Jacob exercised any faith that God would fulfill his promise in answer to Rebekkahs prayer during her pregnancy.
They took it upon themselves to seek to fulfill the promise without waiting for God to do it.
As a result of Jacobs sin, he went into exile for many years fearing his brother would kill him.
So what is the purpose of the story here? What does it mean for Christians in the modern times?
If we also consider the following texts…

Isaiah 61:10 10I will rejoice greatly in the LORD,
my soul will exalt in my God;
for He has clothed me with garments of salvation
and wrapped me in a robe of righteousness,
Hebrews 4:1-16 (i will just quote vs 16 but the entire chapter is
important actually) 16Let us then approach the throne of grace with
confidence, so that we may receive mercy and find grace to help us in
our time of need.
Ephesians 2:8-9 ESV **
** For by grace you have been saved through faith. And this is not your own doing; it is the gift of God, not a result of works, so that
no one may boast.

Jacob tried to obtain the birthright and its blessing by his own hand…his own works. This is not the model that God wishes from us. God wishes us to have faith. The new testament illustrates to us that if we exercise faith, and receive the cloak of Christs righteouness, then we can confidently walk in before the throne of God…Jacob, because of his own works, was anything but confident in walking in before his father…he was terrified he would be found out and cursed. That is the difference between the story of Jacob/Esau and modern Christians…Jacob misunderstood how the promise was to be fulfilled and did not have faith that God would provide.
It is not up to us to use our own works to achieve that gift…“our righteous efforts are nothing but filthy rags to Him” as was clearly demonstrated in the story of Jacob and Esau in that Jacob and his mother thought that obtaining the birthright in their own time frame via deception was ok.
It is never ok to attempt to obtain righteousness our own way via sinful means.
Its interesting that in the New Testament even Nicodemus, a man so intelligent, so well educated… and yet he couldn’t grasp the simplicity of faith and the gospel that Christ was trying to teach him. I certainly suffered the same lack of understanding with this topic as is also illustrated in the story of Nicodemus. *
I was blind to the importance of the illustration of the story of Jacob and Esau and the birthright...specifically of its importance in explaining righteousness by faith.

Jacobs way - by our own works, (the wrong way)

VS

Gods way - through faith as described by Paul and also in the book of Herews (the right way)

It took me almost 24 hours to figure this out…i hope its of use to others as there is an important lesson there in that the gospel and the promise of salvation is a free gift in Gods own time. That it is through our faith that we receive the promise to enter into Gods rest and not our own efforts/works.

In Genesis 26:34-35 it is important to note that Esau made a critical error that disqualified him. He took wives that were Hittites. If Esau was disqualified at the time of the blessing, then Rebekah's concern and action is reasonable. She knows that the promise cannot be through Esau because his Hittite wives had become a "grief of mind" to Isaac and herself. Rebekah should be seen as attempting to be a faithful wife and not allowing her husband to make a mistake. Why Isaac still wanted to bless Esau with Hittite wives must have been confusing for Rebekah.
The blessing of Father to Son is called predestination.
Ps 75:7 - "But God is the Judge:He puts down one, And exalts another."
Ephesians 11:1 - "In Him also we have obtained an inheritance, being predestined according to the purpose of Him who works all things according to the counsel of His will"
In Genesis 25:23 God makes the path of predestination known
the Lord said to her:
“Two nations are in your womb,Two peoples shall be separated from your body;
One people shall be stronger than the other, And the older shall serve the younger.”
25:28 - Isaac loved Esau because he ate of his game, but Rebekah loved Jacob.
Isaac's love for Esau was because of what Esau was giving him. His love was not based on character. Rebekah loved Jacob because he was a mild man.
V.27 "Jacob was a mild man, dwelling in tents."
dwelling in tents is an acknowledgement that everything is temporary and are expectant upon the permanence of eternity with God.
2Cor 5:1 - For we know that if our earthly house of this tabernacle were dissolved, we have a building of God, an house not made with hands, eternal in the heavens.
Jacob at the time of his blessing did not have a relationship with God yet. That came later when Jacob went to Bethel to find a wife in chapter 28.
The fact remains that Esau knowingly sold his birthright prior to all of this.
Genesis 25:32 - And Esau said, “Look, I am about to die; so what is this birthright to me?”
Of course this is symbolic of the new cov. of people who are given a chance to become heirs in the kingdom, and sell off their birthright to appease the flesh (sin)
Esau despised his birthright.
This is the opposite of patient endurance. "Give it to me now", is the fruit of sin gratifying the flesh.
"then he ate and drank, arose, and went his way." This shows complete disregard for the promise. Satisfying pleasures became more important than receiving inheritance. Esau going his own way sums it up, showing departure from the promise.
In contrast, Jacob is patient waiting for his chance to secure the promise.
Hebrews 12:16 -  lest there be any fornicator or profane person like Esau, who for one morsel of food sold his birthright. 17 For you know that afterward, when he wanted to inherit the blessing, he was rejected, for he found no place for repentance, though he sought it diligently with tears.
Isaac had no knowledge of what Esau did. God obviously hated what Esau did and rejected Esau from being the line that Messiah would eventually come through. Whatever sins were committed by Rebekah pales in comparison.
Jacob (whose name means "supplanter, deceiver") has acted in accordance with his name. However after he makes God his God at Bethel, he later wrestles with God and receives a new name Israel, showing the transformation from a sinner to someone who
struggles with God to become righteous.
Was it sin? Yes
Can God still work even though people sin? Yes
Romans 11:29 - For the gifts and calling of God are without repentance.
This means that we are called by God before we come to God in repentance. He calls us while we are in sin, to come out of sin. We are created with a purpose as Jacob was. The sins he committed before coming to the Lord are no different than anyone who has ever existed. This entire story is all about how God has a plan for Jacob even before repentance and is the story of redemption.
It's very easy for Christians to reconcile this, mainly because God has already reconciled it.

Sorry but your answer is deficient. You are openly claiming God gave Jacob the birthright through deception and that it was predetermined. Also, The quotation from the book of Hebrews is misleading...Esau was rejected hecause the blessing had already been stolen and given to someone else...not because God rejected him in that moment. Theweeping of Esau is in reference to the close of probation at the second coming...once the blessing has been received, there is no further hope for salvation. Those are two very different conclusions. Finally, Jacob spent years in excile in fear of his life.

I agree Esau did not value his birthright, selling it for a pot of stew...its the way in which the blessing was received thatis a significant problem. I can answer my own question here btw...after an entire day mulling over it, I've figured out the correct theological answer to the dilemma. I'll give a hint...it relates to salvation by works vs salvation by faith. Remember Abrahams great faith stumbled here when he took Hagar into his bed to fulfill a promise to become a great nation. James tells us works are nothing but filthy rags. (sound familiar?)

I am claiming what it says, that the way was predetermined, and that it was done by man with deception. Do you not think that God already sees how it's going to be done? I never said anything about God doing it through deception, which is what it looks like you are arguing. Either way, Esau was not the elected son to receive the blessing. It was foretold by God because he knew and willed it. You cannot conclude that because God willed the result that He is responsible for the actions of sin.

Esau could be seen here symbolic of Adam who had the messianic line until Jesus the younger brother came in and took it away. The line of promise now continues with Jesus filling the kingdom. Adam giving away his life for food is the same story. Jesus comes in and rescues the line stealing it away from the devil.

@ Biff ... i value your statements there Biff, however, everyone here is missing the point of the story. God did determine that the birthright would go to Jacob...i have not missed that part of the story. They key is, God did not intend that it be obtained via sinful means...ie stolen through trickery! The moral of this story is that Jacob did not exercise faith in God and took it upon himself to take the birthright from his brother whom Jacob did not believe cared for the significance of it. As a result of his sin, Jacob spent the next few years in excile afraid that he would be killed.

following on from above comment...Jacob never actually received the birthright promises from God until his brother Esau had forgiven him...and that was at the same time that God changed his name to Israel (he was no longer Jacob the deceiver). We know that the theology here is true because of the sanctuary service. Israelites could not have unconfessed sin atoned for. Jacob had to make it right with his brother first.

My original answer states that God had nothing to do with the deception that was used to achieve the blessing. I never said anything remotely close to that. Of course Jacob didn't have faith yet, he doesn't start following God until he goes to Bethel in chapter 28. My original answer also included that info.

Throughout the Bible, God uses flawed people to achieve his historical plan. Indeed, all people, whether willingly or otherwise serve his ultimate propose. (As believers we are the beneficiaries or inheritors of this purpose.)

Knowing the family history and what happened in later years proves that what Jacob did then, and later, was entirely legal. Jacob would realise all those events between him, his mother Rebekah, and his twin brother caused God's will to be done, which had been prophetically stated way back.
Esau was a hunter of game, and so taken was he with material things that he sold his birth-right for a meal of red stew. Jacob appreciated the value of the birth-right and cunningly released it from his brother, playing on his brother's weakness. Esau showed contempt for his birth-right giving it away so cheaply. Scripture condemns Esau for having despised it, yet makes no criticism of Jacob.
Afterwards, Esau agrees with his father Isaac to go and get some venison that he might then be blessed. But Esau knew that he had exchanged the blessing and privileges of the firstborn for a bowl of stew. So, he should have owned up to Isaac and said, “No, father, it is Jacob you must bless, not I.” He does not. Deceitfully, he goes hunting to get the blessing. It was Esau who was the supplanter, not Jacob.
Because of the covenant nature of such blessings of inheritance, once stated they could not be changed. That pronouncement to Jacob had been an oracle from God, through Isaac's lips, and he knew it. This is where his FAITH came in - faith in the promise of God. And in Jacob’s old age, God changed his name to Israel (which means 'God fights').
God used events to overrule the natural order to fulfil prophecy about the twins. Read Genesis 25:21-26. Now Jacob had been made Esau's master! The older did, indeed, end up serving the younger. See Genesis 27:37-40. Once the deception was in the open, Isaac then gave Esau another blessing based on what he now knew God wanted him to do.
Finally, all this was linked to the prophecy in Genesis 3:15 as to "the seed of the woman" - it had to come through Jacob - Israel. But Jacob did not have to be "infallible". Yes, he used cunning, yes he used trickery and lied to his near-blind father. But his mother Rebekah knew the prophecy at the birth of the twins, and played her part in the word that God gave to her coming true, which was where HER FAITH also came in - faith in the promise of God. Which is why the New Testament tells us:

"...Rebecca also had conceived by one, by our father Isaac; (For the
children being not yet born, neither having done any good or evil,
that the purpose of God according to election might stand, not of
works, but of him that calleth;) It was said unto her, The elder shall
serve the younger. As it is written, Jacob have I loved, but Esau have
I hated." Romans 9:10-12 K.J.V.


Anne you are advocating salvation by works. Righteousness is by faith, not the works of deception.

@adam  Absolutely not. Both in OT & NT times, those with faith in God have always shown that, if they truly believe the promises of God to them, action is required. Abraham did not sit back and wait for God to stick a magic carpet under him and whisk him off to wherever he was supposed to go. God had not told him where - just, to go. He got up and headed into the unknown, with his entire household. That was not a 'work' - that was faith in action. He was less than entirely honest on 2 occasions when his life was at stake due to having a stunningly beautiful wife. He wasn't 'working' to save

his skin. He knew that if he didn’t say something, Sarah’s role in bearing the seed of promise was in jeopardy. He spoke what had to be spoken. But he wasn’t ‘working’. He spoke in faith. So, with Jacob and Rebekah. The account simply says what happened and what was spoken. It neither commends nor condemns their actions and speech. But we know the outcome was in God’s will and his promises were realised. Who am I to judge those two people of faith? All I know is that they acted in accordance with God’s promises – in faith.

@adam You have condemned Abraham, Jacob, Anne and myself. 'Lies, deceit, took Hagar into his bed, advocating salvation by works'. But 'who is he that condemneth ? is the question. For it is God who hath chosen to justify whom you are so keen to condemn.

@ Nijel...I am simply stating to you what the account of the trickery by which Jacob stole the birthright blessing says.The text plainly tells us, he deceived his father and stole the birthright blessing from Esau. Secondly, your statement I am condemning Abrahams works is false. Abraham was deemed righteous through faith not works...read Romans 4:3,22 Galations 3:6 and James 2:23 Old Testamtent Covenant works is a  flaw in Sunday worshipping church doctrine . The difference between the two is that God writes on our hearts instead of stone in the second. We have always been saved by faith.
